# I want to execute a function after clicking on an image enum in blender python

Tags: python

I am trying out a code that executes a function that change the fps to 30 after clicking an image enum (specifically a single image called Poster1.png)

I just can't get it to work, any help?

[image]
[image]

```
import os
import bpy

# Declare preview_collections as a global variable
preview_collections = {}

def enum_previews_from_directory_items(self, context):
    """EnumProperty callback"""
    enum_items = []

    if context is None:
        return enum_items

    wm = context.window_manager
    directory = wm.my_previews_dir

    # Get the preview collection (defined in register func).
    pcoll = preview_collections["main"]

    if directory == pcoll.my_previews_dir:
        return pcoll.my_previews

    print("Scanning directory: %s" % directory)

    if directory and os.path.exists(directory):
        # Scan the directory for `*.png` files
        image_paths = []
        for fn in os.listdir(directory):
            if fn.lower().endswith(".png"):
                image_paths.append(fn)

        for i, name in enumerate(image_paths):
            # generates a thumbnail preview for a file.
            filepath = os.path.join(directory, name)
            icon = pcoll.get(name)
            if not icon:
                thumb = pcoll.load(name, filepath, 'IMAGE')
            else:
                thumb = pcoll[name]
            enum_items.append((name, name, "", thumb.icon_id, i))

    pcoll.my_previews = enum_items
    pcoll.my_previews_dir = directory
    return pcoll.my_previews


class PreviewsExamplePanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Previews Example Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_previews"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        wm = context.window_manager

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(wm, "my_previews_dir")

        row = layout.row()
        row.template_icon_view(wm, "my_previews")

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(wm, "my_previews")


class IMAGE_OT_preview_clicked(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "image.preview_clicked"
    bl_label = "Preview Clicked"

    def execute(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        clicked_image_name = wm.my_previews  # Name of the clicked image
        print("Image clicked! Name:", clicked_image_name)

        # You can call your custom function here

        # Example: Change FPS to 30 when "Poster1.png" is clicked
        if clicked_image_name == "Poster1.png":
            bpy.context.scene.render.fps = 30
            bpy.context.object.data.update()

        print("end")

        return {'FINISHED'}



def register():
    from bpy.types import WindowManager
    from bpy.props import StringProperty, EnumProperty

    WindowManager.my_previews_dir = StringProperty(
        name="Folder Path",
        subtype='DIR_PATH',
        default=""
    )

    WindowManager.my_previews = EnumProperty(
        items=enum_previews_from_directory_items,
    )

    # Note that preview collections returned by bpy.utils.previews
    # are regular Python objects - you can use them to store custom data.
    #
    # This is especially useful here, since:
    # - It avoids us regenerating the whole enum over and over.
    # - It can store enum_items' strings
    #   (remember you have to keep those strings somewhere in py,
    #   else they get freed and Blender references invalid memory!).
    global preview_collections
    import bpy.utils.previews
    pcoll = bpy.utils.previews.new()
    pcoll.my_previews_dir = ""
    pcoll.my_previews = ()

    preview_collections["main"] = pcoll

    bpy.utils.register_class(PreviewsExamplePanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(IMAGE_OT_preview_clicked)


def unregister():
    from bpy.types import WindowManager

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(IMAGE_OT_preview_clicked)

    del WindowManager.my_previews

    for pcoll in preview_collections.values():
        bpy.utils.previews.remove(pcoll)
    preview_collections.clear()

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(PreviewsExamplePanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```